# Cleverbot.io API not working

Tags: node.js, chatbot

I am making a call to the Cleverbot API using the Cleverbot.io framework. Here is my code:

```
var cleverbot = require('cleverbot.io');
bot = new cleverbot(xxAPI_USERxx,xxAPI_TOKENxx);
const SESSION_NAME = xxSESSION_NAMExx;

bot.setNick(SESSION_NAME);

bot.create(function (err, SESSION_NAME) {
    bot.ask('Hi!', function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

When I run this code, it returns "Error: Bad Call to the API". I also tried calling the API through the site's API Explorer here: https://docs.cleverbot.io/docs/getting-started. I got the same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.the only thing I can think of is that the Cleverbot.io server would be down when you tested this.Try again it would work.If it does not work.

If you still get issues probably tweet your issue to @cleverbotio.

Did not find any other way to reach the cleverbot.io team.

Comment: I've tried over the course of a few hours, and it's still been down. I'll tweet them.

Comment: The base url for the cleverbot.io is https://cleverbot.io/1.0/ which gives an 404 error. if the version is updated then get a new base url and update it.

Comment: That's not the issue. I also tried calling the API through the site's API Explorer; same error. Here is where it is: https://docs.cleverbot.io/docs/getting-started

Comment: This is indeed still an issue. I guess the project has been abandoned...

Comment: @NullDev No, it looks like cleverbot.io simply isn't supported anymore.